# How to remove a user from my telegram contacts using telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I want to remove a user from a client's contact list.

My aim is to remove a user, which was added to the contact list with a phone number, from a contact list of a client.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597384/add-new-contact-in-api-telegram-python-telethon#) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684915/telethon-library-how-to-add-user-by-phone-number) to add a user to a client's contact list. But can't figure out how to remove that user from the contact list.

I have searched for the [telethon doc](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/), And I'm sure it's somewhere in there but found nothing related for hours.

The code to add a user to contact list is this.

```
client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=random.randint(0,9999), phone = "+23xxxxxxxxxx", first_name="fname", last_name="lname")
    result = await client(ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[contact]))

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Please comment if you think my question is not properly written!

Comment: The question is fine and I don't see why it's being flagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so you need to use the raw API requests directly which can be found here. https://tl.telethon.dev/index.html

for your question, the request is DeleteContactsRequest which can be found at https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/delete_contacts.html and can be used as such.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(
        id=['username']
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```